# Is there an objectbox condition, that can filter by string length?

Tags: objectbox, flutter-objectbox

Can I make a database query, with a condition that filters out any elements when a text field doesn't have length 2 or 3 characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in condition for this.

The approach here would be to try to reduce the number of results with built-in conditions as much as possible, then use `.where()` on the result list to filter the results. Wrap this in `store.runInTransactionAsync` to run it on a worker isolate. Something like this:

```
List<User> filterByLength(Store store, String preFilter) {
  var box = store.box<User>();
  final query = box.query(...).build();
  final results = query.find().where(...);
  query.close();
  return results;
}
final results = 
  await store.runInTransactionAsync(TxMode.read, filterByLength, preFilter);
```

https://docs.objectbox.io/getting-started#asynchronous-operations